# How does a server distinguish between multiple requests from same ip address and port?

Tags: networking, ip, webserver, port

When multiple requests are sent to a server to the same poft 80 or whatever and **from the same ip address**, say, from a computer behind NAT or from the same computer but different browsers or by different applications on the same computer, how does a server distinguish between them and is able to reply?

Comment: They don't come _from_ the same port; most clients, and all NATs relaying a client, choose a port not currently in use for the outgoing address. Programs usually have the OS/stack do this automatically by using the sockaddr_in[6].port default of zero.

Answer (score 4):

The client will use a different source port for every TCP session (request), so there are 4 parameters associated with each connection:

- Source IP
- Source port
- Destination IP
- Destination port

As you can see in netstat output, for example my web browser has several connections to the StackExchange network, on different source ports (40092, 40094, 40096):

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.x.42:40092     151.101.129.69:80       TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.x.42:40096     151.101.129.69:80       TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.x.42:40094     151.101.129.69:80       TIME_WAIT
```

The server will be able to differentiate the connections based on the source port used by the client.

Comment: so what if I created a application which sends 100_000  requests simanteniously, how would the source port issue would be solved?

Comment: @Kurama once all available ports are used (you don't have 100000 free ports on one machine, the limit is at 65535), the connections will fail, either waiting for a free port or terminating with an error stating there is no free port to use

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket for more details on network sockets.